# Kotlin: 2 type arguments expected for class Pair<out A, out B> - How can I declare the type of a Pair?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, how can I add the type to a pair of colours:

```
var pair = Pair(Color.RED, Color.WHITE)
```

What would go after the colon in the above?

I need to know since I need to declare an array of `pegColours` but the following gets the error, `2 type arguments expected for class Pair<out A, out B>`.

```
lateinit private var pegColours: Array<Pair>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Pair<out A, out B>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html) has 2 type arguments which you need to specify:

```
lateinit private var pegColours: Array<Pair<Color,Color>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As for your `Pair`, the explicit type can be specified as follows:

```
var pair: Pair<Color, Color> = Pair(Color.RED, Color.WHITE)
```

The `Pair` class defines two `out`-projected generic type arguments, which need to be specified by you. Since you create a pair of `Color`, both types also have to be `Color`.

Comment: Thanks but I accepted miensol's answer as he got there first.